# dart, keeping type checking on but letting proxys through?

Tags: dart, proxy-classes, typechecking

Im passing a proxy object in to a method which expects a specific argument type, the proxy object isn't an instance of the expected type however it does through it's noSuchMethod support all the functionality of the expected concrete type, I want to keep the argument type specification for static type checking whilst I'm coding, I would also like to keep the type checking on whilst I'm debugging my code, but I thought it wouldn't throw type exceptions when the class that causes the error is a proxy object? is there anyway to do this with all the type checking on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement the argument type.

```dart
@proxy
class MyProxy implements MyArgumentType {
  ...
}
```

Comment: the problem is my proxy is such that it implements every type there is in my library, assuming they follow a certain pattern, which they do. and it is used in many places so I'd have to `class MyProxy implements A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I` ... add infinum which just isn't practical :(.

Comment: I'll mark this as the correct answer as for most it will probably be a good solution.